# MongoDB Query an Array of Embedded Documents Via C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, lambda

There is a document in which the Navigation Menu and Menu Items are located.
I didn't get anything from the queries I used. Because it always brought all the elements of the Main Menu. The first Find() method is fine, but the Any() method I created for the embedded document does not give the result I want.

```
public class NavMenu
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public AuthList Auths { get; set; }
    public List<NavMenuItems> MenuItems { get; set; }
}

public class AuthList
{
    public bool Program { get; set; }
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public bool Moderator { get; set; }
    public bool Member { get; set; }
    public bool AnyBody { get; set; }
}

public class NavMenuItems
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public AuthList Auths { get; set; }
}
List<NavMenu> menuList = await collection.Find(m =>
                           m.IsActive && m.Auths.Program &&
                           m.MenuItems.Any(i => i.IsActive && i.Auths.Program)).ToListAsync();
```

Edit : The above query brings me the Menu 1 and all the menu items inside. But I want Menu1 and its sub-items Menu Item 1 and Menu Item 2

```
List<NavMenu> navMenus = new List<NavMenu>();
        List<NavMenuItems> menuItems = new List<NavMenuItems>();
        menuItems.Add(new NavMenuItems
        {
            Name = "MenuItem 1",
            Auths= new AuthList {Admin = false, AnyBody = false, Member = false, Moderator = false, Program = true},
            IsActive = true,
            MenuId = "1",
            Url = "someUrl"
        });
        menuItems.Add(new NavMenuItems
        {
            Name = "MenuItem 2",
            Auths= new AuthList {Admin = false, AnyBody = false, Member = false, Moderator = false, Program = true},
            IsActive = true,
            MenuId = "1",
            Url = "someUrl"
        });
        menuItems.Add(new NavMenuItems
        {
            Name = "MenuItem 3",
            Auths= new AuthList {Admin = true, AnyBody = false, Member = false, Moderator = false, Program = false},
            IsActive = true,
            MenuId = "1",
            Url = "someUrl"
        });
        menuItems.Add(new NavMenuItems
        {
            Name = "MenuItem 4",
            Auths= new AuthList {Admin = false, AnyBody = false, Member = false, Moderator = false, Program = true},
            IsActive = false,
            MenuId = "1",
            Url = "someUrl"
        });
        navMenus.Add(new NavMenu
        {
            Id = "1",
            Auths = new AuthList {Admin = false, AnyBody = false, Member = false, Moderator = false, Program = true},
            IsActive = true, Name = "Menu 1",
            MenuItems = menuItems
        });
```

Comment: *" ... is not working correctly."* - Which mean what exactly? Are you not getting the results you expect? What are you expecting? Better to show some sample documents here and the expected result. The query statement and classes alone tell people little unless there is an outright error. And there appears to be no error. But if you have an error you need to state that exact error in your question as well.

Comment: The query brings me documents that are "IsActive" and "Auths.Program". But it brings together all Menu Items. For example, suppose there are 3 Menu Items. 2 of them are active, 1 are passive. It should only bring me active and Auth.Program menu items. In this scenario, 2 menu items should come. But three are coming.

Comment: *"show some sample documents here and the expected result."* - This is asking you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55062449/edit) and include these details. Your limited words in a comment do not demonstrate much. Show "by example", then we can understand what you mean.

Comment: Sory, but my english very poor. I can't explain what I want exacly. I included details now. I hope it helps understand me.